# In READ COMMITTED isolation, is it possible to read the old value after the update?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to solve an issue with SQL Server 2008 R2 and am grasping at straws.

Given that data is housed in leaf-nodes of the B-tree, and is also exists in indexes, that someone could read multiple values during a single `UPDATE` statement?

Imagine one process updates a row:

```
--Change status from Pending -> Waiting
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   UPDATE Transactions SET Status = 'Waiting'
   WHERE TransactionID = 12345
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Is it possible that during this `BEGIN TRANS; UPDATE; COMMIT` another process could read both new and old values?

I wonder this because the update does not alter a value in only **one** place. That value will exist in multiple places:

- leaf nodes of clustered index
- IX_Tranasctions_1
- IX_Tranasctions_2
- IX_Tranasctions_3
- IX_Tranasctions_4
- IX_Tranasctions_5
- ...
- IX_Tranasctions_n

If the update begins, it has to update values in all these locations. What happens if another process uses an index execution plan to find the value:

- **IX_Clustered**: <strike>Pending</strike> Waiting
- **IX_Transactions_1**: <strike>Pending</strike> Waiting
- **IX_Transactions_2**: <strike>Pending</strike> Waiting
- **IX_Transactions_3**: Pending
- **IX_Transactions_4**: Pending
- **IX_Transactions_5**: Pending
- ...
- **IX_Transactions_n**: Pending

At that instant, if a query is issued that looks at the value in the clustered index it will find **Waiting**.

But if a query uses `IX_Transactions_4` it will find a value of `Pending`.

## Undocumenting the locking mechanism

The lock order internally is undocumented, but i assume SQL Server takes a shared lock on the clustered and non-clustered indexes:

- **IX_Clustered**: Shared
- **IX_Transactions_1**: Shared
- **IX_Transactions_2**: Shared
- **IX_Transactions_3**: Shared
- **IX_Transactions_4**: Shared
- **IX_Transactions_5**: Shared

Then upgrades those locks to Update locks:

- **IX_Clustered**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update
- **IX_Transactions_1**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update
- **IX_Transactions_2**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update
- **IX_Transactions_3**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update
- **IX_Transactions_4**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update
- **IX_Transactions_5**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update

at this point, another process can still read the values in those 5 indexes; because selects are compatible with Update locks.

Then the update proceeds. If we take a picture at an instant in time:

- **IX_Clustered**: <strike>Shared</strike> <strike>Update</strike> Exclusive -> value changed
- **IX_Transactions_1**: <strike>Shared</strike> <strike>Update</strike> Exclusive -> value changed
- **IX_Transactions_2**: <strike>Shared</strike> <strike>Update</strike> Exclusive
- **IX_Transactions_3**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update
- **IX_Transactions_4**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update
- **IX_Transactions_5**: <strike>Shared</strike> Update

Another process can no longer read values from items with an **Exclusive** lock, but it can still read values from items that still have the **Update** lock ([Shared locks are compatible with Update locks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx))

## Unless of course that's not what happens

That only works if SQL only promotes to exclusive as needed. If, instead it goes:

- **IX_Clustered**: <strike>S</strike> <strike>U</strike> <strike>IX</strike> X -> value changed
- **IX_Transactions_1**: <strike>S</strike> <strike>U</strike> <strike>IX</strike> X -> value changed
- **IX_Transactions_2**: <strike>S</strike> <strike>U</strike> <strike>IX</strike> X
- **IX_Transactions_3**: <strike>S</strike> <strike>U</strike> IX
- **IX_Transactions_4**: <strike>S</strike> <strike>U</strike> IX
- **IX_Transactions_5**: <strike>S</strike> <strike>U</strike> IX

And i can't type anymore; my will to continue is crushed. Like i said, i'm grasping at straws.

Comment: Why don't you ask a question about the actual issue you are seeing? It would be useful to know what queries the other process is running and the update statement.

Comment: @MartinSmith i'm finally ready to do that. It's taken 3 days to reproduce the issue, with a (relatively) simple toy model that reliably reproduces horrifying behaviour. i'll have to take some time now to write it all out in a new question.

Comment: @MartinSmith http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58042/how-is-sql-server-returning-both-a-new-value-and-old-value-during-an-update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use trace flag `1200` to print out locking info and `3916` to print logging info. (Both undocumented AFAIK)

For the following test set up

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
A INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
B INT
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON T(B)

INSERT INTO T 
SELECT number
FROM master..spt_values
```

Then running the following twice (as the second run doesn't contain the irrelevant locks acquired during compilation)

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604,1200,3916,-1) WITH NO_INFOMSGS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE T 
SET B += 1
WHERE A = 1000

/*If you habitually have 3604 on then change the below*/
DBCC TRACEOFF(3604,1200,3916,-1) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

This returns the following output

> Process 54 acquiring IX lock on OBJECT: 11:245575913:0  (class
>   bit2000000 ref1) result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring IU lock on PAGE: 11:1:127  (class bit0 ref1)
>   result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring U lock on KEY: 11:72057594039042048
>   (1f00de11a529) (class bit0 ref1) result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring IX lock on PAGE: 11:1:127  (class bit2000000
>   ref0) result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring X lock on KEY: 11:72057594039042048
>   (1f00de11a529) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK
>
> XdesId 0000:00000423: m_logReserved 9162, delta 9162, op
>   LOP_BEGIN_XACT, caller GenerateLogRec, LSN 00000027:00000159:0001.
>
> XdesId 0000:00000423: m_logReserved 9379, delta 217, op
>   LOP_MODIFY_ROW, caller GenerateLogRec, LSN 00000027:00000159:0002.
>
> Process 54 acquiring IX lock on PAGE: 11:1:166  (class bit2000000
>   ref1) result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring X lock on KEY: 11:72057594039107584
>   (dbf572a551f4) (class bit2000000 ref1) result: OK
>
> XdesId 0000:00000423: m_logReserved 9597, delta 218, op
>   LOP_DELETE_ROWS, caller GenerateLogRec, LSN 00000027:00000159:0003.
>
> Process 54 acquiring IX lock on PAGE: 11:1:166  (class bit2000000
>   ref0) result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring RangeI-N lock on KEY: 11:72057594039107584
>   (a39688da7d04) (class bit1000000 ref1) result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring X lock on KEY: 11:72057594039107584
>   (82cbfa4b30c1) (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK
>
> XdesId 0000:00000423: m_logReserved 9671, delta 74, op
>   LOP_INSERT_ROWS, caller GenerateLogRec, LSN 00000027:00000159:0004.
>
> Process 54 releasing lock reference on KEY: 11:72057594039107584
>   (dbf572a551f4)
>
> Process 54 releasing lock reference on PAGE: 11:1:166
>
> Process 54 releasing lock reference on KEY: 11:72057594039042048
>   (1f00de11a529)
>
> Process 54 releasing lock reference on PAGE: 11:1:127
>
> XdesId 0000:00000423: m_logReserved 0, delta -9671, op
>   LOP_COMMIT_XACT, caller GenerateLogRec, LSN 00000027:00000159:0005.

No lock is taken on the non clustered index (`1:166`) until after the `LOP_MODIFY_ROW` update on the clustered index key (on page `1:127`) so yes this would be possible.

And the above is with a narrow (per row) update plan.

With a wide (per index) plan each index is updated in turn. Possibly with intervening sort operations as in the plan below.

[image]

This would make the window of opportunity wider but, whilst a transaction could potentially read the "old" value from an index yet to be updated, it would not be possible for a read committed transaction to read the "new" version of the value until the transaction was committed.

It is certainly possible for a read committed statement to read two different **committed** versions of the same value though.

In one connection run

```
WHILE ( 1 = 1 )
  BEGIN
      UPDATE T
      SET    B += 1
      WHERE  A = 1000;
  END
```

And then in another run

```
SELECT *
FROM   T T1 WITH(READCOMMITTEDLOCK )
       INNER HASH JOIN T T2  WITH(READCOMMITTEDLOCK )
         ON T1.A + 0 = T2.A + 0
WHERE  T1.A = 1000
       AND T2.A = 1000
```

For me about 50% of the time this second query returns a row with different `B` values as the value changes between the two seeks on `T`.